# Run IF till its true then goto Else PHP

Tags: php

I am creating a for loop where i want condition to be like this:

```php
if(get_field('top', $post->ID) == "Yes") 
{ 
    $HeadClass = "first";
    $priority = 1;
} 
else 
{ 
    $priority = 2;
    $HeadClass = "second"; 
}

switch($HeadClass)
{
    case "first":
        $ImgHolderStyle = 'style="position:relative;height:300px;background:#212121;"';
        $ImgStyle = 'style="position:absolute;left:192px;" src="images/img1.jpg" width="300" height="300"';
        $TitleBox = 'title-box';
        $TitleBg = 'bg';
        $NamedClass= '';
        $TitleNewsClass= '';
        $PostTitleClass = '';
        $View = true;
        $ExtraClass = "888";
        break;
    case "second":
        $ImgHolderStyle = 'style="width:235px;height:276px;"';
        $ImgStyle = 'width="240" height="276"';
        $TitleBox = '';
        $TitleBg = '';
        $View = false;
        $ExtraClass = "";
        break;
}
```

in above code i want `IF` condition to be run till its true, then it go to else. I mean according to the occurance of `$HeadClass = "first";` run only if, when this get false then goto to `ELSE`.

What output i am getting id:

```html
<div class="first"></div>
<div class="second"></div>
<div class="second"></div>
<div class="first"></div>
```

What i want to be is:

```html
<div class="first"></div>
<div class="first"></div>
<div class="second"></div>
<div class="second"></div>
```

Comment: Hi. "I am creating a for loop" - where is the loop?

Comment: Just curious, why are you using a switch when you have a if / else clause? I mean you are just doing needless checks, you could move the data from the switch up into the if / else clause.

Comment: Pardon me... This whole code is in loop of While loop. And i just want the final output, plaese share if possible. just want first class to be call first then after second. Any other solutiion.

Comment: You create a while loop that tests the condition and executes the `if` branch internally. When then condition matches the loop is skipped and the `else` branch is executed. _What is the question here?_

Comment: I don't think that the loop is to be left. This looks like wordpress or something similar. Seems like the loop ist to be executed for all posts (of a certain cirteria) and the first _n_ records  (based on this if-condition) get css-set #1 and then the output switches to css-set #2.

Comment: looks like you want to sort your blocks by `top` criteria dynamically, you should make it simpler and sort them beforehand

Answer (score 0):

```
$priority = 1;
while( .... ) {
    if ( 1===$priority && 'Yes'!=get_field('top', $post->ID) ) {
        $priority = 2;

    }

    switch($priority) {
        case 1:
            $HeadClass = 'first';
            $ImgHolderStyle = 'style="position:relative;height:300px;background:#212121;"';
            // ...
            break;

        case 2:
            $HeadClass = "second";
            $ImgHolderStyle = 'style="width:235px;height:276px;"';
            // ...
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Buddy VolkerK .... just now cheking if worked, will so much thanked of u./..... :)

Comment: Usually I don't post just code without a description (or at least comments within the code). But for this I make an exception ;-)   ...or do you have a question regarding the answer?

Comment: No Sir, its perfect. Got a perfect and unique solution. Thanks

Comment: just one more, is there and other solution for calling same classes first then another then next... if yes please share.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question.

Comment: I mean if i am doing some while loop and contents are coming randomly, and i want to be them on order of class names i gave like : first, second.... so the out put what i need is to be : Class First, Class First,Class First, Class Second, Class Second, Class Second, Class third, Class third,Class third, amd more.....

Comment: Oh, that's worth another question. It's wordpress code, isn't it? I don't have any clue of wordpress ;-)